# How can I automate rpmbuild with signing in python?

Tags: python, stdin, popen, gnupg, rpmbuild

Normally you can automate answers to an interactive prompt by piping stdin:

```
import subprocess as sp

cmd = 'rpmbuild --sign --buildroot {}/BUILDROOT -bb {}'.format(TMPDIR, specfile)
p = sp.Popen(cmd, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, stdin=sp.PIPE, universal_newline=True, shell=True)

for out in p.communicate(input='my gpg passphrase\n'):
    print(out)
```

For whatever reason, this is not working for me. I've tried writing to `p.stdin`, before executing `p.communicate()`, I've tried flushing the buffer, I've tried using bytes without `universal_newlines=True`, I've hard coded things, etc. In all scenarios, the command is executed and hangs on:

```
Enter pass phrase:
```

My first hunch was that `stdin` was not the correct file descriptor and that `rpmbuild` was internally calling a `gpg` command, and maybe my input isn't piped. But when I do `p.stdin.close()` I get an `OSerror` about `subprocess` trying to write to the closed descriptor.

What is the rpmbuild command doing to `stdin` that prevents me from writing to it?

Is there a hack I can do? I tried `echo "my passphrase" | rpmbuild ....` as the command but that doesn't work.

I know I can do something with `gpg` like command and sign packages without a passphrase but I kind of want to avoid that.

EDIT:

After some more reading, I realize this is issue is common to commands that require password input, typically using a form of `getpass`.

I see a solution would be to use a library like `pexpect`, but I want something from the standard library. I am going to keep looking, but I think maybe i can try writing to something similar `/dev/tty`.

Comment: RPM *can* be used with GPG keys that are held in an agent, in a hardware store that doesn't require a password, etc. Thus, it's absolutely possible to use RPM signing in cases where password entry on the TTY *isn't needed*. Thus, it's absolutely possible to configure RPM so it doesn't prompt for a password in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

rpm uses getpass(3) which reopens /dev/tty.

There are 2 approaches to automating:
1) create a pseudotty
2) (linux) find the reopened file descriptor in /proc

If scripting, expect(1) has (or had) a short example with pseudotty's that can be used.